# How to deal with unused imports in a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I want to make use of an existing python module (called "module.py"). I'm only interested in one function from that module ("my_function()"). The module also contains a lot of other functions, which I'm not using. These other functions cause the module to have a lot of imports that are not used in my_function.

```
"""module.py"""
import useful_import
import useless_import1
import useless_import2

def my_function():
return useful_import.do()

def other_function1():
return useless_import1.do()

def other_function2():
return useless_import2.do()
```

The code I've written (main.py) imports only my_function, but it still requires me to include/install the other useless modules. I've checked and none of the useless modules run any code on import, so I should be able to safely remove them.

```
"""main.py"""
from module import my_function

print my_function()
```

How do I best deal with this?

- Should I included the useless imports in my project anyway?
- Should I make a copy of module.py and edit it so that it only contains my_function and the right imports?
- Should I copy my_function and its imports into main.py?
- (some other option I didn't think/know of)?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on the context, e.g. how will this code be used later, who will maintain it, what kind of code is it realy etc etc.

But my suggestion under most circumstances would be:

1. refactor my_function and its needed imports into a new_module.py
2. use this module in main.py
3. Either remove module.py from your code base, or have it import from new_module

Comment: If my_function is only ever going to be used in main.py, wouldn't it be better to just copy it into that file, instead of making a new module?

Comment: It would depend on the size (both current and probable), and of how isolated a concept it is. But yes, it might be a good way to go _provided_ you do not have module.py left in your code base.